# C# Hitachi IJP Printer to receive FNC1 symbol

Tags: c#, printing

I having trouble to send FNC1 symbol from my C# software to the printer through network communication.

The printer is Hitachi IJP 2D barcode printer, I had try to use the example from the SDK but there is only able to pass the string/character to the printer.

There sample code is as below :

```
if ( null == this.ijp )
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException ( "Do connect the ink jet printer." );
            }

            // Get the current message.
            IJPMessage message = ( IJPMessage ) this.ijp.GetMessage ();
            if ( 2 > message.Items.Count )
            {
                message.AddColumn ();
            }

            // Change a text.
            message.Items[ 1 ].Text = newText;

            // Set the message.
            this.ijp.SetMessage ( message );
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code? Also, this seems like only a small part of the actual code.

Comment: @JakobTinhofer i would like to add in FNC1 symbol on starting of the barcode string, so that the hitachi ijp printer able to print out accordingly to the separator

Comment: something like *(01)21312312*(10)21321312, i just wanted to send together the FNC1 symbol with the barcode string, however i did not find any information regarding this on the Hitachi SDK documentation

Comment: Ok. I am sorry, but I really do not know enough about the api to answer you your question. I will take a quick look and try to find what I think you mean (I am honestly still not quite sure, sorry).